# Mongodb aggregate query help - grouping with multiple fields and converting to an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, transformation

I have the following document in the mongodb collection

```
[{quarter:'Q1',project:'project1',user:'u1',cost:'100'},
{quarter:'Q2',project:'project1',user:'u2',cost:'100'},
{quarter:'Q3',project:'project1',user:'u1',cost:'200'},
{quarter:'Q1',project:'project2',user:'u2',cost:'200'},
{quarter:'Q2',project:'project2',user:'u1',cost:'300'},
{quarter:'Q3',project:'project2',user:'u2',cost:'300'}]
```

i need to generate an output which will sum the cost based on quarter and project and put it in the format so that it can be rendered in the Extjs chart.

```
[{quarter:'Q1','project1':100,'project2':200,'project3':300},
{quarter:'Q2','project1':100,'project2':200,'project3':300},
{quarter:'Q3','project1':100,'project2':200,'project3':300}]
```

i have tried various permutations and combinations of aggregates but couldnt really come up with a pipeline. your help or direction is greatly appreciated

Comment: That is one document that you need transformed into one document? The user in the original document is irrelevant?

Comment: @Jinxcat the answer supplied shows a method for doing such transformations in the aggregation pipeline if this interests you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cost data appears to be strings, which isn't helping, but assuming you're around that:

The main component is the [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator in the document projection, and assuming your data is larger and you want to group the results:

```
db.mstats.aggregate([
    // Optionaly match first depending on what you are doing

    // Sum up cost for each quarter and project
    {$group: {_id: { quarter: "$quarter", project: "$project" }, cost: {$sum: "$cost" }}},

    // Change the "projection" in $group, using $cond to add a key per "project" value
    // We use $sum and the false case of 0 to fill in values not in the row.
    // These will then group on the key adding the real cost and 0 together.
    {$group: { 
        _id: "$_id.quarter",
        project1: {$sum: {$cond:[ {$eq: [ "$_id.project", "project1" ]}, "$cost",  0 ]}},
        project2: {$sum: {$cond:[ {$eq: [ "$_id.project", "project2" ]}, "$cost",  0 ]}}
    }},

    // Change the document to have the "quarter" key
    {$project: { _id:0, quarter: "$_id", project1: 1, project2: 1}},

    // Optionall sort by quarter
    {$sort: {quarter: 1 }}
])
```

So after doing the initial grouping the document is altered with use of [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to determine if the value of a key is going to go into the new key name. Essentially this asks if the current value of `project` is "project1" then put the `cost` value into this `project1` key. And so on.

As we put a 0 value into this new document key when there was no match, we need to group the results again in order to merge the documents. Sorting is optional, but probably what you want for a chart.

Naturally you will have to build this up dynamically and probably query for the `project` keys that you want. But otherwise this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Niel thank you for your solution. yes project keys are dynamic so i guess i need to query this first and create the query based on it. thanks for the solution